# How to set the TestCase custom property value as a parameter in Xpath in Property transfer

Tags: soapui

I m trying to add a property transfer from rest response to a test case level custom property. From Rest response, I want to exact 'id' by 'name' and set the value as test case level property
My XPath is as follows

```
//*:e[*:name = '${#TestCase#CLContractName}']/*:id
```

But this is returning null  
If I directly set the value then it's setting the value correctly

```
//*:e[*:name = 'LAI-00151007']/*:id
```

My sample xml as follows

```
<Response xmlns="https://training-app.labs.com/api/v1/investor">
<items>
<e>
<id>48223</id>
<name>LAI-00151007</name>
<amount>25050.0</amount>
<interest_rate>25.99</interest_rate>
<term>60</term>
</e>
<e>
<id>48262</id>
<name>LAI-00152581</name>
<amount>44225.0</amount>
<interest_rate>18.9</interest_rate>
<term>36</term>
</items>
<total_count>13</total_count>
</Response>
```

Please advise me what is the correct format and what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned way is the correct way to set the property value. After the investigation, I found that I am getting null because the test case property value is empty otherwise its correct

```
    //*:e[*:name = '${#TestCase#CLContractName}']/*:id
```